# gem5 syscall emulation hello world falls into an infinite event loop without running any instructions

Tags: gem5

When I ran a paper's open source code, such a problem occurred.

```
333333333: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000

666666666: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000

999999999: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000

1333333332: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000

1666666665: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000
1999999998: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000

2333333331: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000
```

it seems enter an endless loop. I saw the corresponding DPRINTF in src/cpu/base.cc. under what circumstance will such a problem occur? Do anyone know the reason ? or can you provide some suggestions on how to find the problem ?I've been stuck in this problem for two weeks.Thanks

Comment: Have you examined `ExecAll` and tried to correlate it to the source code? What is the full gem5 CLI? Does the problem happen if you use more simple features e.g. AtomicSimpleCPU vs DerivO3CPU?

Comment: Yeal, when I use AtomicSimpleCPU,It works fine.But my work is correlate to the DerivO3CPU and I changed some code in gem5. The above error information appeared when I ran Hello_world program with setting the debug = ExecAll. Moreover ,Except for the above error information,there were no other output,including those assembly instruction that should be output.It droped into a infinite loop

Comment: "Except for the above error information,there were no other output,including those assembly instruction that should be output" so all the expected instructions showed up and then it went into a infinite loop? Or no instructions showed up at all? If some but not all showed, try to determine where it got stuck based on the instructions. Sometimes it is easy, sometimes it is hard.

Comment: All the exceptd instructions didn't show up. no assembly instructions appear. The output is all like "xxxxxxx: Event_61: system.cpu progress event, total committed:0, progress insts committed: 0, IPC: 00000000". Only the previous tick is changing, as shown in the question, the tick increases by 333333333 each time, and then it falls into an endless loop.

Comment: In that case, this will be easy to debug, if you provide a minimal reproducible example someone might debug it for you (gem5 version, gem5 CLI, hello world source and how you built it including GCC/OS version), and consider opening a bug report at https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5 . I would even start with a freestanding Linux assembly hello world (nothing before `main`) example that runs your known instruction immediately if it can reproduce there.